# cURL con array, solo toma primer valor

Tags: php, curl, sms

mi problema es que estoy enviando parametros a traves de cURL a un modem GSM que tengo... con un chip para enviar mensajes de texto... todo funciona bien, cuando cuando recorro un array con los destinos es cuando falla... solo envia al primer elemento del array y los demas no... no se si algo me falta o me sobra 
tengo estos códigos:

**curl.php**

```
<?php

function Enviar($Mensaje,$Destino){
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mi.modem.gsm.lol/sms.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxx:xxxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Send=Send&max_digit=".$Mensaje."&sms_number=".$Destino);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if($output === FALSE){
echo 'cURLL Error:'.curl_error($ch);
return FALSE;
}

curl_close($ch);
return TRUE;

//print_r($output);


}
?>
```

**Enviar.php**

```
    <?php
include 'curl.php';
$Destinos = array("xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxxxxx");
//var_dump($Destinos);
$Mensaje = "Mensaje de prueba desde el servidor...";

$NDestinos = count($Destinos);

for($i=0;$i<$NDestinos;$i++){
$respuesta = Enviar($Mensaje,$Destinos[$i]);

if($respuesta){
echo "enviado ".$Destinos[$i]."<br>";
}else{
echo "no envia";
}
}

?>
```

gracias de ante mano!

Comment: Es decir que al final imprime 1 mensaje de 'enviado' y 2 de 'no envia'?

Comment: imprime 'enviado' para todos los casos... pero el mensaje solo llega al primer numero...

Comment: Probaste si intercambiando el arreglo `('1xxxxx', '2xxxxx', '3xxxxx');` por `('3xxxxx', '2xxxxx', '1xxxxx');` envia el mensaje al otro numero, es decir al 3 suponiendo este caso?

Comment: asi es... intercambien el orden de los numeros y solo llega al primero...

Comment: intentastes hacer el curl en consola uno a uno, de igual forma creo que la linea del post debe ser algo como `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Comment: Si te refieres a enviar manuammente a los destinos, si lo hice y normal llegan, el problema escuandl envio por el array...

Comment: en el peor de los casos trata de colocar un [delay](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usleep.php)

Comment: agregue un sleed(10) en el bucle y si funciono!, lo que me preocupa es que tengo que enviar mas de 500 mensajes (es un recordatorio de citas para pacientes de un hospital) no le tomara mucho tiempo?

Comment: @LeeChevarria coloca menos tiempo, si utilizas sleep es en segundos 10x500=5000segundos.. Jack te recomendo usleep(x) que utiliza microsegundos.

Comment: Creo que sería más eficiente si inicias una sola sesión `cURL`, y una vez iniciada haces el envío sin tener que abir/cerrar `cURL` cada vez. O sea, abrir tu bucle `for` y meter esto dentro: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Send=Send&max_digit=".$Mensaje."&sms_number=".$Destinos[$i]);
$output = curl_exec($ch);` Puedes ir guardando el resultado de `$output` en un array en cada paso del bucle y al final imprimir un reporte de lo que ocurrió en cada iteracción. Y luego al salir del `for` cierras `cURL`. Creo que ganarías muchísimo en eficiencia del código.